# Using "event" keyword twice in the same scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, electron, event-handling

I have a function that is called via an event listener on click. It takes in an event parameter:

```
function editExistingEmp(event)
```

This function, when called, will loop through all the DOM content looking for DOM elements with a specific ID, and then dynamically adding an event listener to that element:

```
nodeHandler.addEventListener("click", function() { selectNodeEdit(event); }, false);
```

My issue is now these new event listeners are sending the event data that is originally received from the function as a parameter. But I need these new event listeners to pass in their event data from the DOM element they were added to still, NOT the parameter event passed into the function.

Comment: `event` is not a keyword; it's just a variable name. In the `function` expression in the `addEventListener()` call, add `event` as a parameter.

Comment: Also, "id" attribute values in the DOM must be *unique*; using the same id on more than one element is erroneous.

Comment: To avoid confusion and shadowing, use a different variable name for the nested event. `function(e) { selectNodeEdit(e); }`

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is now these new event listeners are sending the event data that is originally received from the function as a parameter.

Right, because the handlers you're creating in the function close over the `event` parameter.

> But I need these new event listeners to pass in their event data from the DOM element they were added to still, NOT the parameter event passed into the function.

You're explicitly passing them the parameter passed to the function. To avoid that, don't pass them the parameter. It sounds like you want the parameter to be passed to them by the event system. In that case, the simplest thing to do is to remove your wrapper function:

```
nodeHandler.addEventListener("click", selectNodeEdit, false);
```

That passes the `selectNodeEdit` function to `addEventListener`; the event system will call it with the relevant event object as an argument, which it will receive as its first parameter.

You *could* still have a wrapper if you wanted to, by accepting the parameter and passing it on:

```
// No need for this in most cases
nodeHandler.addEventListener("click", (event) => selectNodeEdit(event), false);
```

...but there's no need for that in most cases. (As [Barmar points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77143996/using-event-keyword-twice-in-the-same-scope-in-javascript/77144076#comment135996782_77143996), if you did, you might consider using a different name for one of those, just to avoid confusion. Doing that isn't *necessary*, but it could be useful. But again, there's no need for the wrapper function at all anyway.)

---

A couple of side notes:

1. Re

   > Using "event" keyword twice in the same scope in JavaScript?

   You weren't using them in the same scope. You were using the parameter in a *nested* scope within the `editExistingEmp` function.
2. `event` isn't a keyword in JavaScript. In your code, it's the name of the first parameter to `editExistingEmp`. There's also an automatic global variable with the name `event`, but using it is not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

To pass event data from dynamically added event listeners to the 'editExistingEmp' function, use a closure to capture the local event data from the DOM element they're attached to, rather than the original event parameter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).